# Native javascript with ZK?

Tags: java, javascript, openlayers, zk

Is it possible to use native javascript with the ZK Framework. (I would like to integrate the OpenLayers library) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is quite easy to use pure Javascript with ZK. You can use ZK's client side programming techniques to integrate any 3rd party Javascript library. Please refer to [ZK Client-side programming](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming) and [Integrate 3rd party Javascript Libraries with ZK](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/October/Integrate_3rd_Party_Javascript_Libraries_In_ZK)

Specific to OpenLayers, ZK team has already integrated it as a ZK component. You can refer to this [ZK Openlayers Integration blogpost](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2012/07/03/zk-openlayers-integration/) about the usage and more details. Not sure if you know but ZK also has [google maps component](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Guide/ZUL_Components/Wrapped/Gmaps) which is more mature and already in use in production

Comment: Thank you. I know about the Openlayers component but since it is not mature. I said maybe doing it natively will save me from bugs that appears later. 
(PS: I am not interested with google maps)

Comment: I see. I would suggest poking in [ZK Openlayers github](https://github.com/zkoss/openlayers) repo. Especially client-side code [here](https://github.com/zkoss/openlayers/tree/master/src/main/resources/web/js/openlayers)